# Good resources for video processing in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming, video-processing

I am using the yolov3 model running on several surveillance cameras. Besides this I also run tensorflow models on these surveillaince streams. I feel a little lost when it comes to using anything but opencv for rtsp streaming.

So far I haven't seen people use anything but opencv in python. Are there any places I should be looking into. Please feel free to chime in.

Sorry if the question is a bit vague, but I really don't know how to put this better. Feel free to edit mods.

Comment: Can you say which yolov3 model you are using? Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course are the alternatives to OpenCV in python if it comes to video capture but in my experience none of them preformed better

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess my real problem is scaling